# Select picture from android gallery (not a camera picture) and user input text and save it to an app folder to be recalled in a new activity

Tags: android, text, save, gallery

I am trying to build an android app that on one activity "onClick" opens the native picture gallery and allows you to pick an image and store it in a folder within the app to be recalled and presented in a different activity. The same with user input text. A user inputs text in a textbox, "onClick" saves this text to be recalled later in a different activity. I have tried several different codes to make this happen and I get errors.

Any help with example code would be appreciated.

Comment: The image and text are permanent or temporary? means the app is one time run or the data should always exist?

Comment: Both are permanent once the user selects picture or inputs text. I can create a new folder within the app to store this information to be recalled every time the user opens the app.